# What's the best way that we know how to measure the complexity of a math problem that a human is to solve?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, problem-solving

A brief search online and in ##math in libera irc yielded no results. I'm guessing this question is one for both mathematicians and psychologists.

My first thoughts are that one would have to understand the essence of the problem, and understand at a precise level how ones reasoning skills are used to solve the problem. I figured there must be researchers who have thought of this before.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking, how involved is the proof of a theorem? If the length of a program is something one can measure (e.g. Kolmogorov complexity) then by the Curry-Howard correspondence so should be the length of a proof.

Comment: No best  way I think. Solving a mathematical problem is an act of creation with a specificity very different from writing a poem or a novel or composing music, but which in the depths of things participates of the same creative “élan”. Wanting to go to a better explanation, it seems to me that it requires raising different levels of demand, for which both the willingness to face the problem and the "information" on the point to be discussed are necessary. (suite)

Comment: And the full perception of the real complexity of the problem would be a very difficult point to pin down because it would depend on the scope of the mind and the mathematical culture of each individual.